# Can signals be parameters in Qt?

Tags: qt, function, pointers, signals

A function: `void function(ObjectName obj, Signal)`, `ObjectName` is a class type and `obj` is an instance. The question is that can the second parameter be a signal which defined in class `ObjectName`. That means can I use the signal as a normal member function pointer?

Comment: What might this function do with that signal? Connect to it? Call it to cause the signal to be emitted? You're digging a little into the internals of signals with this and the answer to your question depends on what piece of the signal sending and receiving mechanism you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!  Think about it -- QObject::connect() is a function that takes both signals and slots as parameters.  Check out [its documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) for the various ways this can be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I try it and the conclusion is: get failure in my Windows but Success in Linux and Windows PC of my friend.... I don't know why maybe something wrong with my system but it doesn't necessary, my program will be running on Linux.